# Jquery Jqgrid dialog overlay not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, overlay

I'm using JGrid and the overlay does not work in IE 11, it does not occupy the whole screen. I applied the fix from other posts here in stackoverflow but it did not work.

[image]

Here's the css code:

```
.ui-jqgrid .jqgrid-overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which options of form editing (of the options of `navGrid`) you use? It would be easier if you post the demo, which reproduces the problem. Try [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/37/) for example, which uses free jqGrid 4.15.0. The overlay `.ui-widget-overlay` seems have no problem.

Comment: added linked image to the post

Comment: @Oleg im using Guriddo jqGrid JS - v4.8.2 and im using delete option

Comment: @JunaldBayog: It seems a bug in *commercial* [Guriddo](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use. I develop *alternative fork* [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I provide provided completely free of charge  under MIT and GPL. Sorry, but I can't help you with Guriddo.

Comment: @Oleg i tried the demo of Guriddo here [link](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs) and the overlay is working fine in ie11, i wonder why it wouldn't work in my project

Comment: @JunaldBayog: Probably you should upgrade jqGrid, which you use? The version 4.8.2 is mare as 2.5 years old.

Comment: @Oleg will try thanks

Comment: @Oleg can i use the free version instead? is that possible? thanks

Comment: Yes of cause. It can be used by everyone for free. You need mostly replace URLs of jqGrid files. You can load the files from CDN: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.0/jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. If you use English locale then you should remove `grid.locale-en.js`. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for more details and code examples.